# Update-manager not showing items

Tags: updates, update-manager

My update-manager isn't showing any items to update.
it does show the total amount of data to be downloaded.
and number of programs to be updated.
and when hitting the update button it does update.

when i use command promt everything shows up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two cases:

1. You system is up to date.
2. You may have unchecked the options to update from **Update Manager**->**Settings**

So, you should go for *2nd* option to be sure that everything is alright.

- Open Update Manager
- Click <kbd>**Settings...**</kbd> button ( it may ask your password ).
- Select(tick) all the **Check Boxes** on the tabs **Ubuntu Software**, **Other Software** and **Update**. On **Update** tab Chose **Automatically check for updates: <kbd>Daily</kbd>**. Then <kbd>Close</kbd>
- It should scan the available updates and will list all. Click <kbd>Check</kbd> to scan again. <kbd>Install Updates</kbd> would update your system.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: thanks for you're help, but as i mentioned it does show a total amount of KB to be downloaded / updated. but it wil not show wich items to update. when using terminal apt-get upgrade it shows all the items needed to upgrade.